# How to make child-navigation not affect parent browser history?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, browser

I have a main page which contains a simple iframe. Iframe source = a php file.
The PHP have a link the user can click, but whenever clicked, the browser history increases.

I want the iframe to be independent, without affecting history.
Possible? I am not familiar with ajax btw.

PS: Its only 1 link in the iframe which can be clicked.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing that comes to my mind is to use [`location.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.location) to change the URL in the iframe , when the link is clicked.

That method doesn't store the current page in the browser's session history, for example:

```
<a href="http://google.com"
   onclick="location.replace(this.href);return false;"/>Google</a>
```

Or connecting the event programmatically:

```
<a href="http://google.com" id="linkId">Google</a>
```

...

```
document.getElementById('linkId').onclick = function () {
  location.replace(this.href);
  return false;
};
```

Check an example [here](http://jsbin.com/ufeji).